# How to specify a custom output path to CoffeeScript files in WebStorm 6

Tags: coffeescript, webstorm

How to specify a custom output path to  CoffeeScript files in WebStorm 6?
I create a new File watcher for CoffeScript, and in the watcher Settings I have tried to set output paths like "$ProjectFileDir$\js\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js",
but It doesn't work. why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Output directory should be specified like this:

`--output $ProjectFileDir$\js --map --compile $FileName$`

[image: output]

`Output paths` setting is used for tracking of the produced files in the project view tree, it doesn't specify the compiler output path.